# Checking for number of digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following function which is supposed to check for the number to be 4 digits.

```
   function f_checkNum(
       @pnum integer
    ) returns integer
    begin      
       return case
                when @pnum like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then 1       
                else 0
             end;      
    end
```

This works fine if numbers entered are under 4 digits but if they are over 4 it gives error

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: How much over 4 digits? 5?

Comment: Try taking pnum as varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Return CASE WHEN @pnum between 1000 and 9999 Then 1 Else 0 End
```

If you need to include negative numbers then

```
Return CASE WHEN ABS(@pnum) between 1000 and 9999 Then 1 Else 0 End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
return case
    when LEN(cast(@pnum as varchar)) = 4 then 1
    else 0
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that function instead. This will check for the length of your number and cater for negative numbers as well.

```
create function f_checkNum(
   @pnum integer
) returns integer
begin  
return case when len(cast(@pnum as varchar(max))) = 4 and @pnum > 0
    then 1
    else 0
    end
end
```